# how to fill an input field with keydown/keyup/keypress with casperjs?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

there is an input field bind with keydown/keyup/keypress/blur event,
and want to fill some value to this input field 
 with casperjs

```
<input type="text" class="some-input" id="somekey" 
onblur="somefunc_1();" 
onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13)  somefunc_2();"
onkeyup="somefunc_3();" onkeypress="return somefunc_4();">
```

this is what i try with casperjs, but it's no work:

```
var somevalue = '3';
casper.then(function(){
        this.mouseEvent( 'click', '#somekey');
        this.page.sendEvent('keypress', somevalue);
        });

casper.wait(1000, function(){
        console.log("input value :" + 
        this.getElementAttribute('#somekey', 'value')); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementAttribute is not going to get the value. After playing around with some code, I came up with this which seems to work.

```
    casper.then(function(){
    this.sendKeys('#somekey', 'just testing this');
    test.comment(this.evaluate(function(){
        return __utils__.getFieldValue('nameOfSomeKeyField');
    }));        
});
```

Comment: I get the error :  Untitled suite in testTour.js
    error: SyntaxError: Parse error. What can I do?

Comment: I would suggest looking over the code for syntax errors or missing ";" and the like.